# While deploying on Heroku Nodemon Not Installing

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

```
2020-10-29T10:56:28.471077+00:00 app[web.1]: > facedetection_api@1.0.0 start /app
2020-10-29T10:56:28.471078+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon Server.js
2020-10-29T10:56:28.471078+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-29T10:56:28.477851+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2020-10-29T10:56:28.490614+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-10-29T10:56:28.490976+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-10-29T10:56:28.491195+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-10-29T10:56:28.491486+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-10-29T10:56:28.498461+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! facedetection_api@1.0.0 start: `nodemon Server.js`
2020-10-29T10:56:28.498645+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-10-29T10:56:28.498878+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-10-29T10:56:28.499056+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the facedetection_api@1.0.0 start script.
2020-10-29T10:56:28.499235+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-10-29T10:56:28.506217+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-29T10:56:28.506435+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-10-29T10:56:28.506583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-29T10_56_28_500Z-debug.log
2020-10-29T10:56:28.574097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-29T10:56:28.620761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-29T10:56:28.624053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-29T10:56:31.374327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-29T10:56:34.282119+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-29T10:56:34.282146+00:00 app[web.1]: > facedetection_api@1.0.0 start /app
2020-10-29T10:56:34.282147+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon Server.js
2020-10-29T10:56:34.282147+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-29T10:56:34.293033+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2020-10-29T10:56:34.304933+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-10-29T10:56:34.305387+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-10-29T10:56:34.305760+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-10-29T10:56:34.306156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-10-29T10:56:34.313422+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! facedetection_api@1.0.0 start: `nodemon Server.js`
2020-10-29T10:56:34.313565+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-10-29T10:56:34.313774+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-10-29T10:56:34.313917+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the facedetection_api@1.0.0 start script.
2020-10-29T10:56:34.314110+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-10-29T10:56:34.321573+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-29T10:56:34.321833+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-10-29T10:56:34.322020+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-29T10_56_34_315Z-debug.log
2020-10-29T10:56:34.393688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-29T10:56:34.444159+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-29T10:56:38.810884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wildwood-57505.herokuapp.com request_id=9b7759d0-c425-4a7e-883e-28f67e1ce1c9 fwd="103.82.80.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-29T10:56:39.445550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-wildwood-57505.herokuapp.com request_id=d342dce6-167f-4b7b-a7b6-ffdaa1c38b6f fwd="103.82.80.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can Anyone Tell that why nodemon is not installing on Heroku I tried the article which already available on Stach Overflow not worked for me  ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047981/node-js-heroku-deployment-on-mac-sh-1-nodemon-not-found-npm-err-nodemon#:~:text=Heroku%20runs%20in%20a%20production,npm%20script%2C%20in%20your%20package."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047981/node-js-heroku-deployment-on-mac-sh-1-nodemon-not-found-npm-err-nodemon#:%7E:text=Heroku%20runs%20in%20a%20production,npm%20script%2C%20in%20your%20package.%22))

Comment: You don't need nodemon in production. You can start your server by updating the start script to "start": "node Server.js",

Comment: Thanks a lot I understand your words.

Comment: nodemon is just used as a dev dependency.